# global array doesn't get modified in javascript function

Tags: javascript, global-variables

I've been spending way too much time on this issue... So i want to declare a 2D array called "positions" that can be used in other functions. using a parsing code that worked in the function "init", i tried to create a simple function called "parsing" as to avoid repeating the long parsing process every time i want to use the positions array. except when i console.log(positions) in other functions, it always returns an empty array = [].
How come "positions" doesn't get modified in the parsing function and how do i do it? This is the code used:

```
var positions = [];

parsing();
init();

function parsing() {
    fetch('Petit_film_256_atomes.txt').then(response => response.text()).then(text => {
        const arr = text.split('\n')
            .map(line => line.trim())
            .map((arr) => arr.split(' '))
            .map(([size, x, y, z]) => ({ 
                  size: Number(size), 
                  x: Number(x), 
                  y: Number(y), 
                  z: Number(z) 
            }));
            while (arr.length > 0) {
                positions.push(arr.splice(0, size).slice(2));
            }
    })
}
```

Comment: Because you have an asynchronous call and act like ti is synchronous.

Comment: Just put the `init` call inside the `then` callback as well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I haven't looked closely at what's happening during all the `.map` calls, but the trouble is probably that `parsing` is not finished by the time `init` is invoked. You can try it this way:

```
var positions = [];

parsing(init);

function parsing(cb) {
    fetch('Petit_film_256_atomes.txt').then(response => response.text()).then(text => {
        const arr = text.split('\n')
            .map(line => line.trim())
            .map((arr) => arr.split(' '))
            .map(([size, x, y, z]) => ({ 
                size: Number(size), 
                x: Number(x), 
                y: Number(y), 
                z: Number(z) 
        }));
        while (arr.length > 0) {
            positions.push(arr.splice(0, size).slice(2));
        }
        if (typeof(cb) === 'function') {
            cb();
        }
   })
}
```

Comment: Don't take a callback. Use the promise that you have, and return it! `parsing().then(init)`